# module located in python3 not reachable

Tags: python-3.x, shebang

I got 2 shell script file start with

1. ## !/usr/bin/env python
2. ## !/usr/local/bin/python3

both shell script uses "import cchardet"

first one errors " ImportError: No module named cchardet "

but, second one works perfect.

problem is, I need to use first one's script. Is there way around?

and also, is cchardet stuck in python3 environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cchardet is not part of the standard library, so you must have installed it using pip3 and it's available in fact to python3.

To have it available to python install it with pip like:

```
pip install cchardet
```

Comment: thank you. eventually found out that cchardet can be accessed by python3